# create a list containing tables in R

Tags: r, list, loops, entropy

I have the following dataset in `R` and I want to calculate Shannon's entropy. In order to do that since the data are continuous, I have to discretise them. Using the `discretize2d` function of `Entropy` package, the entropy between $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be calculated as follows:

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- matrix(rnorm(150 * 11, mean = 0, sd = 1), 150, 11)

library(entropy)
dis <- discretize2d(data[,1],data[,2], numBins1 = 10, numBins2 = 10)

entropy(dis)
```

I want to create a `list` containing all the `discretize2d` results between between the variables of `data` so i can later just use `entropy(dis$1.2)` and getting the same result as `entropy(dis)`. Can someone help me code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an all-base R solution. We use the `combn(x, m)` function to generate all combinations of the elements of `x` with size `m`. Here we want pairs so `m = 2`. This creates a 2 by 55 matrix. Then use `apply()` to iteratively apply `discretize2d()` over columns of that matrix. The second argument of `apply()` is 2, meaning to apply over columns. We also specify `simplify = FALSE` so that the result will stay a list rather than being coerced to an array.

```
combs <- combn(1:ncol(data), 2)
dis <- apply(combs, 2, function(x) discretize2d(dat[, x[1]], dat[, x[2]], numBins1 = 10, numBins2 = 10), simplify = FALSE)
```

If you want names for the elements like you specified, such as `dis$1.2`, you can do this:

```
names(dis) <- apply(combs, 2, paste, collapse = '.')
```

Finally you could also calculate entropy for all elements at once with `lapply()`:

```
lapply(dis, entropy)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very well explained and works perfectly! I have tried the 'combs' function but not combined with the 'apply'

Comment: Is there anyway i can utilise the 'lapply' function in order to find the marginal entropies? For example "entropy(rowSums(dis$`1.2`)) = 2.163956'. Can i generalise it like  the 'lapply(dis, entropy)' ?

Comment: Yes, you just need to define a function and apply it. Either define the function separately and then apply it, like this `f <- function(x) entropy(rowSums(x)); lapply(dis, f)`, or inline like this `lapply(dis, function(x) entropy(rowSums(x)))`

Comment: Thanks, just right now i did it with a double lapply:  'lapply(lapply(dis,rowSums), entropy)', which results in the same as yours.